# cmis configuration alfresco cloud

Tags: 7

I'd like to use the Alfresco Cloud ECM with my Drupal instance. I created an alfresco site. I installed and activated the CMIS module. Here is my configuration script:

```
$conf['cmis_repositories'] = array(
    'default' => array(
      'label' => 'cmis.alfresco.com',
      'user' => 'my_alfreso_cloud_username@example.de',
      'password' => 'my_alfreso_cloud_password',
      'url' => 'https://cmis.alfresco.com/cmisatom'
    ),
  );
```

I only find these lines to configure the module. Then I added a CMIS field to my content type. When I add a new node then there is an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: `cmis_field_rootFolderPath` in `cmis_field_field_widget_form()` (line 123 of D:\Inetpub\SK1913\sites\all\modules\cmis\cmis_field\cmis_field.module).

I cannot find any other configuration forms (beside the root path setting).

What am I doing wrong? Does this module work with the alfreso cloud solution? I don't want to install alfreson on my server until I know how to use it, or even **if** I use it...

Comment: Which of CMIS modules you use? https://drupal.org/project/cmis, https://drupal.org/project/cmis_alfresco, https://drupal.org/project/cmis_views ?..

Comment: Please [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/112261/edit) to make module name a link to module you are actually using. It will make answering easier for future readers, and will save information you provided if comments are deleted (they are meant to be ephemeral, you know).

Comment: I use the [drupal.org/project/cmis](https://drupal.org/project/cmis), not the [drupal.org/project/cmis_alfresco](https://drupal.org/project/cmis_alfresco), Not yet the [drupal.org/project/cmis_views](https://drupal.org/project/cmis_views)

Comment: The watchdog gives the following messages: `HTTP call to [https://cmis.alfresco.com/cmisatom] returned [0]. Response: ` The URL seems to be incorrect. When I use the http instead of the https, there is another message: `HTTP call to [http://cmis.alfresco.com/cmisatom] returned [403]. Response: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 - Error report HTTP Status 403 - 04061021301 Failed to authenticatetype Status reportmessage 04061021301 Failed to authenticatedescription Access to the specified resource (04061021301 Failed to authenticate) has been forbidden.Apache Tomcat/6.0.29`

Comment: **[EDIT](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/112261/edit)**

Comment: Just to close this case: I installed the alfresco server and now the CMIS module works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one more configuration in setting.php for content type mapping with its fields.

In this example i have mapped article content type with cmis type.

```
$conf['cmis_sync_map'] = array(
 'article' => array(
     'enabled' => TRUE,
     'cmis_sync_cron_enabled' => TRUE,
     'cmis_folderPath' => '/Sites/New/Article',
     'full_sync_next_cron' => TRUE,
     'cmis_sync_nodeapi_enabled' => TRUE,
     'subfolders' => TRUE,
     'cmis_type' => 'alf:article',
     'content_field' => 'body',
   ),
);

$conf['cmis_sync_map']['article']['fields'] = array(
  array('drupal' => 'title', 'cmis' => 'cmis:name', 'drupal to cmis' => TRUE, 'cmis to drupal' => TRUE),
  array('drupal' => 'body', 'cmis' => 'cm:content', 'drupal to cmis' => TRUE, 'cmis to drupal' => TRUE),
  array('drupal' => 'field_object_id', 'cmis' => 'cmis:objectId', 'drupal to cmis' => TRUE, 'cmis to drupal' => TRUE),
);
```

I hope it will works for you.